# Bootstrap Website does not work on IE

Tags: javascript, php, html, internet-explorer

I have developed this website using Bootstrap. Now some of the javascript and styling is not recognised by IE, which is pretty weird!

Here is the link :

{http://--162.243.241.231--/blue/calculator.html}

Any solutions or ideas are kindly appreciated!

Comment: Which IE version are you using? On IE 11 it works fine for me.

Comment: Yup fine for me on, IE 11

Comment: What exactly is your issue ? the appearance looks just fine.

Comment: Hello, yes the layout is fine but for some reason the coloring is not supported!In chrome the toolbar ids completely RED while in IE is fading. You can try it yourself and you will see the difference!

Comment: Even this ` <a href="http://www.viessmann.com/dealerLocator/search/gb/index.html" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" type="button" href="#myCarousel">Find an installer</button></a>` is not working on IE a simple HREFed button!

Answer (score 1):

For the styling - have a separate stylesheet for IE-only and put it in your `<head>` with all regular CSS, example below:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="IE.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

If you want to specify what IE version:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="IE9.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: `if IE == 9 then load IE7` ?

Comment: Edited my answer, but it does not really matter what your stylesheet is named. Call it IE_is_the_best_browser.css if you want to.

Comment: That would be some illogical naming :)